# How to fix: Text overflowing DIV in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a DIV (.main) that contains a background-image. A TOS text overlays the background image. Everything is fine when the browsers window is extended, but once I shrink it too much down, the text from TOS overflow the image.

You can see the problem LIVE by going on my website and resizing the window.
https://royalkingdom.net/store/

I've already tried to play with the padding, margins, max-height and max-width.

```
/* Main column */
.main {
  flex:60%;
  height:940px;
  margin-bottom:10vh;
  padding-right:8%;
}
#bgimg {
 position: relative;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/NPhmcae.png");
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center top; ;
 display: block;
 padding-top:13%;
 padding-right:10%;
 padding-left:10%;
 padding-bottom:13%;

}
.panel-body {
  text-align:justify;
  padding:1px;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

I expect to have the text to fit the image size. Even when I resize my browser window. It is fine if it needs to have a scrollbar (when the window size is too small)

Comment: add a media query to reduce the size of the text

Comment: I would try adding `overflow-y: auto:`

As Rachel said you could try adding a media query, but I would instead make the div's height larger if you can.

Comment: @CallumR I've tried overflow-y but it still goes out of the div. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to add is `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ej5dh46u/2/) that I set up to mimic your div. That second 100% forces the image to be the full width of the div, as the image was not expanding with the height of the div. If you take away that second 100% in the JSFiddle you will see that the red border still expands but the image does not.

```css
#div2{
    background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/NPhmcae.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    display: block;
    padding-top:13%;
    padding-right:10%;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-bottom:13%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non. Imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
  </p> 
</div>
```

One problem you might encounter is if you have too much/too little text the image will be greatly distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code -

```
.panel-body {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 1px;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 75vh;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n5maii 

It only adds the scrollbar and it still go over the image/div

Comment: Try resizing the window smaller until the text overflow the image :/